# How get list of apps icons and names in kotlin to recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

so im new in kotlin im trying to get all installed apps on device to recycler view my problem is every thing from activity in recycler adapter return null even I pass context

this is my code :

```
class Games_listx  : RecyclerView.Adapter<Games_listx.viewxlist>() {

    var appsx = Gamesff()
    var listofapps  = ArrayList<String>()
    var  all_apps : MutableList<ApplicationInfo>? = null
    var icons  : Drawable? = null

    class viewxlist(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val txt_game = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.txtgames) as TextView
        val im_game = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.imgames) as ImageView
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Games_listx.viewxlist {




        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)

        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lay_allgames,parent,false)


        all_apps = appsx.activity?.packageManager?.getInstalledApplications(0)
        Log.w("apps" , "app " + all_apps?.size)

        for (app in all_apps?.indices!!) {
            val name = all_apps?.get(app)?.loadLabel(appsx.activity?.packageManager!!)

            if  (!(name?.startsWith("com.")!!)) {
                listofapps.add(name?.toString())
            }

        }
        return viewxlist(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

       return listofapps.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Games_listx.viewxlist, position: Int) {


        holder.txt_game.text = listofapps.get(position).toString()




    }

}
```

listofapps has 0 size and package manager is null

i use same code to get apps in onstart and it work

what I'm doing wrong

how I can get activity or context without being null in adapter

recyclerview in fragment

```
class Gamesff : Fragment() {





override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()



}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val viewx = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gamesff,container,false)

    val all_games_list = viewx.findViewById<View>(R.id.gamelistfounds) as RecyclerView
    val add_game_folder = viewx.findViewById(R.id.txtaddgamefolder) as TextView









    add_game_folder.setOnClickListener {

        Toast.makeText(activity,"Make your own gaming folder",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        val i = Intent(activity,GamingFolder::class.java)
        i.action = "add"

        startActivity(i)

    }


    val gridlay = GridLayoutManager(activity,4,GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false)

    all_games_list.layoutManager = gridlay
    all_games_list.fitsSystemWindows = true
    all_games_list.hasFixedSize()
    all_games_list.adapter = Games_listx()


    return viewx
}
```

Comment: `onCreateViewHolder` is called repeatedly, once for every visible list item view group in your RecyclerView. If your list is empty, it will never be called in the first place. You need to create your data list and populate it outside your adapter class, and then pass the prepared list of data to your adapter.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks i know how adapter works in java you can progress your data in adapter and can access to context but in kotlin it always return null it must be way

Comment: It works the same way in Kotlin and Java. You’re fetching your list of installed applications in `onCreateViewHolder()`, which doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @Tenfour04the so how can pass drawables from application info in activity to adapter they not path to save in array is that any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of *separation of concerns* your adapter should not be responsible for searching for the data to show.

First, have a data class for the information of each application that is relevant for your RecyclerView to show or act on, for example:

```
data class AppInfo (
    val appName: String,
    val packageName: String,
    val icon: Drawable
)
```

Your Adapter should expose a public property for the data list. This is how any Adapter should work. You create your views and ViewHolder in `onCreateViewHolder` and bind your values in `onBindViewHolder`. I like to set up the ViewHolder to handle this internally, so my onBind and onCreate functions are very simple. I also expose a single property for an item click listener, so the click functionality is also handled externally. The adapter doesn't do anything except connect the data and logic to the views.

```
class AppsListAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<AppsListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    inner class ViewHolder(val rootView: ViewGroup): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(rootView), View.OnClickListener {

        init { rootView.onClickListener = this }

        val titleView = rootView.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.title)
        val iconView = rootView.findViewById<ImageView>(android.R.id.icon)

        var data: AppInfo? = null
            set(value) {
                field = value
                value ?: return
                titleView.text = value.appName
                iconView.setImageDrawable(value.icon)
            }

        override fun onClick(v: View) {
            data?.let {
                onListItemClick(it)
            }
        }
    }

    fun interface OnItemClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(appInfo: AppInfo)
    }

    var dataList: List<AppInfo> = emptyList()
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    private var onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener? = null
    
    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: OnItemClickListener) 
        this.onItemClickListener = listener
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.app_list_item, parent, false)
        )

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.data = dataList[position]
    }
}
```

Then in your Activity or Fragment or ViewModel, you can fetch all the data, using a coroutine so the loading of drawables doesn't happen on the main thread. In my case, I do this in a ViewModel and populate a SharedFlow that the UI is subscribed to, but for simplicity, since you mentioned Activity, here's how you could do it in an Activity:

```
val adapter = AppsListAdapter()
adapter.setOnItemClickListener { // Set what to do when item is clicked
    Log.d("item click", "Clicked package ${it.packageName}")
    
}
myRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

lifecycleScope.launch {
    val packageManager = context.packageManager
    val appsData = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { // do all loading in background thread
        packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)
            .filterNot { it.packageName.startsWith("com.") } // any filtering you want before loading
            .map {
                AppInfo(
                    it.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString(),
                    it.packageName,
                    it.applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager)
                )
            }
    }
    adapter.dataList = appsData
}
```

Actually, since the user might have many apps installed, I also support early cancellation of the coroutine after getting the initial list and every fifth icon loaded like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val packageManager = context.packageManager
    val appsData = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { 
        packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)
            .filterNot { it.packageName.startsWith("com.") }
            .mapIndexed { idx, it ->
                if (idx % 5 == 0) yield()
                AppsInfo(
                    it.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString(),
                    it.packageName,
                    it.applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager)
                )
            }
    }
    adapter.dataList = appsData
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer its full answer now I know how kotlin works I find my problem, one more thing how make if not in kotlin in java like this if (!s.startwith(...)) {} how I can do this in kotlin?

Comment: That would be exactly the same in Kotlin

Comment: i use this if (!string.startwith("") {} in kotlin for not startwith but ! error unresolved reference appears

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you want a way to initialize your data in the adapter.
The thing you are doing wrong is trying to initialize the list in the `onCreateViewHolder()`. Before `onCreateViewHolder()` gets called, `getItemCount()` will be called. It will return 0 and because it returned 0 `onCreateViewHolder()` will never be called. What you should be doing is initialize your `listofapps` inside the `constructor()`

```
class AppsAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<AppsAdapter.AppsViewHolder>() {

private var list: MutableList<App> = ArrayList()

constructor(packageManager: PackageManager): this() {
    val packageInfos = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)
    for (packageInfo in packageInfos) {
        val appName = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager) as String
        if (appName.startsWith("com.", true)) {
            continue
        }
        val appDrawable = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager)
        list.add(App(appDrawable, appName))
    }
}



override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AppsViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_app, parent, false)
    return AppsViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AppsViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.onBind(list[position])
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return list.size
}

class AppsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun onBind(app: App) {
        val appIcon = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.appIconImageView)
        val textView = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.appNameTextView)
        appIcon.setImageDrawable(app.appIcon)
        textView.text = app.appName
    }
}}
```

Where App.kt is:

```
class App (val appIcon: Drawable, val appName: String)
```

And in MainActivity you should:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var adapter: AppsAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    adapter = AppsAdapter(packageManager)
    val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(
        this,
        4,
        GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
        false
    )
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
}}
```